# Wifi password on motorola SBG941 reverts after a short period of time following a change

Tags: wireless-networking, router, passwords

So, I have a Motorola SBG941 router and I'd like to change the wireless password from the default, in theory this should work fine.

And it does... sorta, I can change the password but it reverts after a few hours, ditto for name.
I'd also like to enable a guest account, this seems to work with a slight caveat, the settings revert in the router config utility but the network is up with the same name as I set and the same password, so long I don't touch the guest wifi settings (which is non-ideal as I'd like to be able to disable it without losing the entire config).

Comment: This a router or gateway, if a gateway, contact your service provider and ask for a firmware update

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, it sounds like your settings changes stick, except if you edit the Guest Wi-Fi settings, in which case everything reverts to defaults.

This sounds like a bug in the firmware, where the code that stores the Guest Wi-Fi settings is corrupting the router's configuration file (or database, or whatever kind of data structure your router uses to store its configuration data), so the router has to throw it all away and revert to defaults.

Look for a way to update the firmware on your router. Maybe it's a bug that Motorola has already fixed.

Comment: Well, the settings don't stick at all.
The main wifi network resets to factory defaults no matter what, the guest wifi sticks partially (the settings revert back to disabled with the default name MOTOROLA_GUEST but the network is still broadcast on the name specified (the settings indicate disabled))
Either way I'll see if I can find a firmware update.

Comment: Note also that cable gateways often have remote management features (TR069, etc.) that allow your ISP's support techs to push firmware updates or fix settings for you. It's possible that something's gone haywire and your ISP's management system keeps pushing default settings to your gateway.

Comment: Really now? I don't think they should have that sort of access if they do, that just sounds like a security hole to me.
Assuming they are doing that however then I don't think I can get it to work at all (which is a tad annoying)